# CCK field in node template

Tags: entities, nodes, theming

If I have a custom CCK field, for example "temperature", is there any way I can directly call it from the node template? Like would there be a $temperature variable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access it directly from the node variable like: $node->field_temperature[0]['view'].

If you want to see what values are actually on the node, I'd suggest `var_dump($node);` in the template to check out what fields/values you can access.

Comment: so using that, I could output it in the node, right? Thank you!

Comment: yeah, so for example if you created a template in your theme for the node, like "node-thermometer.tpl.php" for a content type of thermometer, you would be able to use that to output the temperature on the thermometer.